# Проблемы с ObjectInputStream\ObjectOutputStream, считывание и запись объектов в файл

Tags: java, файлы, объекты, потоки-данных

Здравствуйте. Класс(IdentificationUser) производит идентификацию пользователя(User),приложение сетевой чат. В качестве тренировки, я хочу чтобы у меня все пользователи чата хранились в одном файле. При регистрации нового пользователя он заносился в файл. При авторизации читался бы файл, и сравнивался на соответствие ввода и прочтенного объекта из файла.Классы Output и Input предназначены для вывода/ввода информации на экран.

```
package clients;

import exceptions.InputException;
import input_output.Input;
import input_output.Output;

import java.io.*;

public class IdentificationUser {
private Output out;
private Input in;
private File userList;

//первоначальное меню и выбор пользователя
public User show() {
    out = new Output();
    in = new Input();
    out.login();
    try {
        switch(in.getIntChoice(2)){
            case 1:
                return login();
            case 2:
                return createNewUserAndLogin();
        }
    } catch (InputException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}

//Вход в систему уже зарегестрированого пользователя
private User login() {
    out = new Output();
    userList = new File("list.bin");
    out.userLoginInfo();
    User checkUser = new User(in.createUserName(),in.createUserPassword());
    try(ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(userList))){
        while (objectInputStream.available() > 0) {
            User tempUser = (User) objectInputStream.readObject();
            if (tempUser.equals(checkUser)){
                return checkUser;
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

//Создание нового пользователя и занесение его в файл с пользователями
private User createNewUserAndLogin() {
    out = new Output();
    userList = new File("list.bin");
    out.userLoginInfo();
    User user = new User(in.createUserName(), in.createUserPassword());
    try(ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(userList,true))){
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(user);
        return user;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

После удачного занесения в файл пользователей, при авторизации считывается только первый объект в файле удачно, далее следует ошибка:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: AC
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readBlockHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:2964)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.available(ObjectInputStream.java:3110)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.available(ObjectInputStream.java:944)
at clients.IdentificationUser.login(IdentificationUser.java:43)
at clients.IdentificationUser.show(IdentificationUser.java:24)
at Main.main(Main.java:12)
```

В общем я понимаю что при записи в файл записывается хэдер,а после объект. И при считывании он мешает. Но как пересматривать объекты из файла все равно не понимаю. Подскажите конкретный код в данной ситуации, что мне надо поменять,чтобы оно заработало?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как Вы правильно поняли, это происходит из-за того, что [`ObjectOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) записывает заголовок, описанный в методе [`writeStreamHeader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeStreamHeader--):

> The writeStreamHeader method is provided so subclasses can append or prepend their own header to the stream. It writes the magic number and version to the stream.

Соответственно, чтобы заголовок не писать можно создать наследника `ObjectOutputStream` и  переопределить этот метод (код из [ответа Andreas_D в на англоязычном сайте](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194656/appending-to-an-objectoutputstream/1195078#1195078)):

```
public class AppendingObjectOutputStream extends ObjectOutputStream {

    public AppendingObjectOutputStream(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        super(out);
    }

    @Override
    protected void writeStreamHeader() throws IOException {
        //требуется для повторной записи объектов, см. ссылки
        reset();
    }
}
```

После этого нужно написать код, который будет писать заголовок для первого пользователя (нового файла) и дополнять файл без заголовка для последующих пользователей:

```
/**
 * Вспомогательный метод для создания потока
 */
private static ObjectOutputStream createStream(File userList) throws IOException {
        return userList.exists()
                ? new AppendingObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(userList, true))
                : new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(userList, true));
}

private static User createNewUserAndLogin() throws Exception {
    File userList = new File("list.bin");
    try (ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = createStream(userList)) {
         ...
```

Можно также сделать класс более узкоспециализированным и перенести в него логику определения необходимости заголовока.

Похожие вопросы на английском:

- [Appending to an ObjectOutputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194656/appending-to-an-objectoutputstream/1195078#1195078)
- [ClassCastException when Appending Object OutputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12279245/classcastexception-when-appending-object-outputstream/12438141#12438141)

P.S. Присоединяюсь к предложению @zolt использовать более удобное и надежное хранилище для пользователей. В текущей реализации одна неудачная запись испортит весь список пользователей. Также будет сложно реализовать простые улучшения: например добавить новое поле в класс `User`.

Answer (score 1):

Может все-таки не в файлах юзверей хранить? Можно взять какую-нибудь БД, H2 например, или HSQL. Они умеют работать просто в памяти, или хранить себя в файле. Ну Вам останется лишь взаимодействовать с ними через JDBC драйвер. База это надежней просто файлов, уж поверьте.